# jstack results in "Windbg Error: WaitForEvent failed"

Tags: java, windows, jstack

On Windows 7, I try to get a stack trace from a Java process by executing the command

> jstack.exe -F xxx

from another Java process, where xxx is the PID of the target process.  I'm getting the error

> Error attaching to process: Windbg Error: WaitForEvent failed!

Any idea why?

Comment: Because I left the company for which i asked my initial question, I somehow have to abandon it.

Answer (score 6):

It might be that you need to run the command as administrator. If you do not have access rights to the process you will also get that same error message.

Answer (score 2):

One of the possibilities (which may not be your case) is simply incorrect PID (see [JDK-6313817 : SA: jstack -F on win32 needs more friendly handling of wrong PID](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6313817))